# how to show hidden table in mysql database

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a database name `visualresume` which contains total 4 tables following:

1. `user`
2. `signup`
3. `educationqualification`
4. `professionalqualification`

But by mistake I clicked on `eye sign` and two tables were hidden from my database. How to show them again?

Comment: There is is another eye sign next to your database. click on that and choose items to be shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next to your database should appear a light bulb, click there to unhide them.